# Identity column insert not working when bulk copying using c#

Tags: c#, insert, ssis, identity

I have a SOURCE table as below in Prod:

```
    SELECT '-1' as PKey, NULL as ID, 'Unknown' as Name
    UNION
    SELECT '1' as PKey, 01 as ID, 'ABC' as Name
    UNION
    SELECT '2' as PKey, 02 as ID, 'XYZ' as Name
```

I want to replicate (move) it to DEV environment. For this I have a Foreach loop container with following three tasks:

1) Identity_Insert ON: Checks if the table has any identity column or not, if Yes, then set it to ON (I have tested this and it works)

2) Script_task_1: This uses the following code to move the data from PROD to DEV

```
    try{
        string connectionString =
                @"Data Source=Prod_Server;Initial Catalog=Source_DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        // get the source data
        using (SqlConnection sourceConnection =
                new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand myCommand =
                new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + TableName, sourceConnection);
            sourceConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            // open the destination data
            string connectionString1 = @"Data Source=Dev_Server;Initial Catalog=Dest_DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

            using (SqlConnection destinationConnection =
                        new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
            {
                // open the connection
                destinationConnection.Open();

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
                {
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 500;
                    bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 1000;
                    bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied +=
                        new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TableName;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            //MessageBox.Show("Data copied successfully!!");
        }
        }
            catch(Exception E){
                Console.WriteLine(E.Message);
            }
```

3) Identity_Insert OFF: Checks if the table has any identity column or not, if Yes, then set it to OFF

After this process..My destination table is looking like this:

```
    SELECT '1' as PKey, NULL as ID, 'Unknown' as Name
    UNION
    SELECT '2' as PKey, 01 as ID, 'ABC' as Name
    UNION
    SELECT '3' as PKey, 02 as ID, 'XYZ' as Name
```

So, it is copying the data properly, but the Identity field for the root record is not replicating. instead of being -1, it is starting at 1.

Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to look at the KeepIdentity section of the [bulk insert books online documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You are right buddy..I have updated the script to include 'SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity'..but that still is not helping..still getting the same result

Comment: The other thing that I notice is that you are using *.  I would explicitly map the columns. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx I know the documentation says if the columns count and position are the same it doesn't matter, but when it comes to identity columns SQL can get too smart. To see if this is the right path run DBCC CHECKIDENT to reseed the column to 25 and then run the import if the values turn into 26, 27, 28 the identity is running.